# Reading emails from office365 Outlook account using Java

Tags: jakarta-mail, office365

We have a requirement to read emails from an Office365 account and show them in our Java EE application. We have done it using JavaMail and its working as expected; but the issue is with performance. Its taking around 30 secs to 3 minutes to read the emails depending on the size of mail or attachments. Is there any way we can improve this performance ? Following are few more details of the approach we have taken.

1. We are retrieving the mails using IMAPStore
2. The emails that we need to read are not inside inbox. Its in a different folder outside of it. This folder again has sub-folders which holds the filtered emails based on the subject.
3. While reading the mails we read from a particular folder then show them in our application in the same hierarchy as they are present in the mail server.

We thought of different alternative approaches like reading from a PST file or storing the emails into our database by a background process then reading from the DB but none of them really worked out. 
Is there any other way of doing this. We found there is a Office365 SDK for android, can we make use of that ?

Comment: Hey guys, solved the problem? Can you help me here(stackoverflow.com/q/36483341/3703397)?

Answer (score 1):

First, [it's not "JEE", it's "Java EE"](https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE).

You haven't really provided any details on exactly what you're doing that takes 30 seconds to 3 minutes.  Is it reading 1 message?  Is it reading 1000 messages?

And what exactly do you mean by "reading" the message?  Just displaying the header information, or displaying all the message content as well?

Does the time include the time to connect to the server and open the folder?  Or just the time to access the message(s) after you've opened the folder?

Have you looked at the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug)?  If you use java.util.logging to get timestamped logging output, you might be able to tell which operation is taking the time.

Are you using the [Folder.fetch](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#fetch(javax.mail.Message[],%20javax.mail.FetchProfile)) method to prefetch the message data in bulk?

Why do you believe that it isn't just Office365 that's slow?

With more details we might be able to provide more hints for how to improve the performance of your program.

Comment: The time that i have mentioned is inclusive of all. We are displaying the mails using pagination and per page we are showing 25 mails for now. Following are the steps we are performing. 1. First we login to the mail server and get the total email count. 2. Using this count we are deciding the number of pages. 3. Then we read only the header information of the first 25 emails, along with this we retrieve the names of the attachments also (if any).  During all these time we show a "Loading"  ticker. Once we have the response from mail server we load our screen, this is taking that time.

Comment: After this when the user clicks on the consequent pages we connect to the server again and fetch next 25 mails. Regarding JavaMail debug output, we will check that. And yes we are using Folder.fetch. If you want I can share the code with you for your reference.

Comment: You need to isolate the part of your program that's taking the most time.  If you think it's the JavaMail part, isolate that into a program that fetches the data from the server but doesn't do anything with it.  If that's still too slow, most likely the problem is that the mail server is slow, but by looking at the debug output we can determine if you're doing thing inefficiently and could improve how you interact with the server.  You might use the [msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) as a starting point or as a performance test with Office365.

Comment: After timing different operations we found that its taking 10 - 15 seconds to login to the mail server, then for reading the header information and attachment name its taking 1 second for each email. so to display 25 emails headers only it needs more than 35 seconds. I guess you are right about Office365 being slow. Is there any way to reduce the time its taking for login only.

Comment: Typically most of the login time is on the server while it's verifying your authentication information, so there's not much you can do about it.  You could certainly dig into the performance of connecting and logging in on the off chance that there might be something you could improve, but it's unlikely.  As for headers and such, using the Folder.fetch method usually helps quite a  bit.  Either post the debug output or send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com and we can see if there's further optimization possible.

Comment: Thanks Bill :) I am going to send the debug output and the code to your email ID.

Comment: Hey guys, hey, solved the problem? Can you help me here(http://stackoverflow.com/q/36483341/3703397)?