# IMAP access to mail office 365 with javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, office365, java-5

I'm trying to read the emails in a folder of an email account Office365 using JavaMail 1.4 api.

My code is:

```
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    // Get a Properties object
    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    // Get a Session object
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    // Get a Store object
    Store store = null;
    Folder rf = null;

    if (CUR_MAIL_PROTOCOL != null)
        store = session.getStore("imap");

    // Connect
    if (CUR_MAIL_HOST != null || CUR_MAIL_LOGIN != null || CUR_MAIL_PWD != null)
        store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "**MYEMAIL**", "**MYPASS**");
    else
        store.connect();

    // List namespace
    rf = store.getDefaultFolder();

    getFolderDetails(rf, true, "");
    if ((rf.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS) != 0) {
        Folder[] f = rf.list("%");
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
            getFolderDetails(f[i], recursive, "    ");
    }

    store.close();
}
```

My error is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect;
  nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:298)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:234)
```

Thanks

PS: Account Office365 using JavaMail 1.4 api

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: ok :D

Now i have this error:

DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [QQBNADMAUABSADAANQBDAEEAMAAyADEALgBlAHUAcgBwAHIAZAAwADUALgBwAHIAbwBkAC4AbwB1AHQAbABvAG8AawAuAGMAbwBtAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
A1 LOGIN XXX@xxx.com *****
A1 BAD Command received in Invalid state.

Comment: Basic the error is: LOGIN A1 BAD Command received in Invalid state.

Comment: Try using `imaps` instead of `imap`. With `imap`, the server is returning the `LOGINDISABLED` capability, which means that you can't issue a simple username/password `LOGIN` command. That shouldn't be the case with `imaps`.

Comment: did you manage to found a way to access office365 via imaps? can you post a solution?

Answer (score 6):

PFB Code this resolves.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.FetchProfile;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

public class OutLookReader_imaps {

    Folder inbox;

    // Constructor of the calss.

    public OutLookReader_imaps() {
        System.out.println("Inside MailReader()...");
        final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        // Set manual Properties
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", "993");
        props.put("mail.imaps.host", "outlook.office365.com");


        try {
            /* Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "My email ID", "my password");

            /* Mention the folder name which you want to read. */


            inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");

            /* Open the inbox using store. */

            //inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(
                    Flags.Flag.ANSWERED), false));
            //Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();

            System.out.println("No. of Unread Messages : " + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());
            System.out.println("No. of Messages : " + inbox.getMessageCount());
            System.out.println("No. of Deleted Messages : " + inbox.getMode());

            FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
            fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);

            inbox.fetch(messages, fp);

            try {

                printAllMessages(messages);

                inbox.close(true);
                store.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception arise at the time of read mail");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while connecting to server: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }

    }

    public void printAllMessages(Message[] msgs) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            printEnvelope(msgs[i]);
        }
    }

    public void printEnvelope(Message message) throws Exception {

        Address[] a;

        if ((a = message.getFrom()) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Email From : " + a[j].toString());
            }
        }

        String subject = message.getSubject();

        Date receivedDate = message.getReceivedDate();
        Date sentDate = message.getSentDate(); 

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        System.out.println("Email Subject : " + subject);

        if (receivedDate != null) {
            System.out.println("Received Date: " + df.format(receivedDate));
        }

        System.out.println("Sent Date : " + df.format(sentDate));
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new OutLookReader_imaps();
    }
}
```

Comment: stil I am getting error :-
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.

Actually I am trying to read the mail from my office email which is 'office 365' .
Could you please tell me, what configuration or properties value I am missing ?

Comment: Does this still work?  I am getting a MessagingException:  A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.  I know I have the right password because I can connect with pop3s, it's just imaps that I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what was missing was:

```
 props.setProperty("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms","XOAUTH2")
```

all props working for me (both gmail and o365):

```
"mail.imaps.ssl.enable"         true
"mail.imaps.sasl.enable"        true
"mail.imaps.auth.login.disable" true
"mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable" true
"mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms"    "XOAUTH2"
"mail.imaps.usesocketchannels"  true
"mail.event.scope"              "session"
"mail.imaps.starttls.enable"    true
"mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms"    "XOAUTH2"
```